# Why does adding functions to my script make it load significantly slower?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to get into data algorithmic trading in python and am certainly a beginner. I tried to break up my code using functions and it significantly increased loading time to the point where im forced to force quit the application.

Here's the link to my code: https://github.com/dsturdy/Algo-Trading-Part-One/commit/334f4935c785bda694a2a648030c29afc2d5ccc6#diff-e612eb836465c89f509cf1257db4348175853e7ee1f887474ef179bf6fd75419

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Create a minimum, verifiable example that exhibits the problem and _include the code in your question_. External links to code are not searchable, doesn't show proper context of what you've added and where you think the issue is, and can change at any time, making the question and any answers far less valuable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Too many function calls in Python do make the code slow, and Python is already a slow language by itself. Library functions and pre-defined functions are usually faster than defining your own functions, so try using those if they are available.

[This](https://pawroman.dev/how-not-to-be-slow-using-python-functions/) is a good guide as to why certain code (including functions) may make Python run very slowly.